# What will happen if I downvote someone while I have 125 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, privileges

Do I lose the privileges given for having 125 reputation or do they persist once you achieved the threshold once?

Comment: Quick! Someone go upvote the OP so he can't test it!

Comment: You have the privileges that match your reputation. A drop in rep might mean you lose those privileges again.

Comment: Downvote an answer for science... find out. You'll have a few minutes to undo your downvote before it's locked in.

Comment: @Bart, I have marked it as a duplicate too. I tried too strict of a search before I posted.

Comment: Don't worry. Not all of use spend such an insane amount of time on Meta as some of use do. I know there was a dupe. Makes it easier to look for it. :)